# How to fix TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'

Tags: python

I don't know how to fix this error. I hope some of you can help me. I really appreciate.
This code in Python :

```
import numpy as np
from calendar import monthrange
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r2T2m = np.loadtxt("E:\koppen-master\R_THANHHOA_1998_2019.txt",comments="#")

nyr = len(r2T2m[:,1])/31    
nyr = int(nyr)

print("number of the years", nyr)

r3T2m = np.reshape(r2T2m[:,1:13],(nyr,31,12))

r2T2m_mn = np.zeros(shape=(nyr,12))

iyr = 0    
while iyr < nyr:

    imn = 0         
    while imn < 12:

        idy = 0     
        ndy = 0 
        ndy_of_mn = monthrange(1998 + iyr, imn+1)

        while idy <31:

            if r3T2m[iyr][idy][imn] >= -10.:  

                ndy = ndy + 1
                r2T2m_mn[iyr][imn] = r2T2m_mn[iyr][imn]+r3T2m[iyr][idy][imn]

            idy = idy+1

        r2T2m_mn[iyr][imn] = round((r2T2m_mn[iyr][imn]*ndy_of_mn)/float(ndy),2)
        imn = imn + 1

    print("Year:", iyr+1998, "  ", r2T2m_mn[iyr])
    iyr = iyr + 1
```

Data I used :

[image]

Error message Which I am getting :

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'

how to solve the issue?

Comment: Please reformat your code [(see)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: At which line are you getting the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
r2T2m_mn[iyr][imn] = round((r2T2m_mn[iyr][imn]*ndy_of_mn)/float(ndy),2)
```

Here `ndy_of_mn` is a **tuple** [see](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange), but `r2T2m_mn[iyr][imn]` is a float. You cannot multiply these two things.

**More explanation**

By looking at this line

```
ndy_of_mn = monthrange(1998 + iyr, imn+1)
```

I understand that you want to compute number of days in a month (is that right?). However, `monthrange` returns weekday of first day of the month and number of days in month **as a tuple**. And you only want the second part of this tuple. Therefore why don't you do something like this:

```
_, ndy_of_mn = monthrange(1998 + iyr, imn+1)
```

That way `ndy_of_mn` is not a tuple anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. How can I get the solution ?

Comment: @ViệtNguyễnĐức Did you check the link I shared above?

Comment: Yes, I got it. "Returns weekday of first day of the month and number of days in month, for the specified year and month."

Comment: @ViệtNguyễnĐức I included more explanation

Comment: Oh I just did a lot of complicated ways. Thank you so much for your help. It's more simple than I thought. It's work now.

Comment: One more thing that I want to run this program for multiple txt files, not just 1. Do you know how to solve this ? I have started working with python for my internship 2-3 months so a lot of things I don't know. Thank you so much for your time

Comment: @ViệtNguyễnĐức I don't know what you are doing here and what your goal is. That sounds like a whole different problem. If you want, you can post a different question and explain what is your struggle and also explain what your code does.